# what are the good ways to migrate the Hdd SAS from bad server to the good server without lose data

Tags: raid, sas

I have a  problem with a HP ProLiant ML350 G6 with 2 SAS HDD 300GB :
I shut it down for add a network card, but it won't start.

I have changed (migrate) the HDD to an other good server,
 But both HDD were ok, with green lights.

I can't find how to see or enter in the raid configuration ?

what are the good ways to migrate the Hdd sas from bad server to the good serverand keeping  os and tdata in the hdd

Please help Thank you

Comment: Why did the original server not start again? Because of a disk error? What happens if you remove the added NIC?

Comment: i already removed the NIC but , the same problem  the server cant start , the two UPS are okey , and i think that the problem in the power because no light , dispalyed in server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a very dangerous situation.

Simply moving disks to another server does not guarantee being able to boot back up or read out data from them, on the contrary, you risk losing access to your data.

RAID data may be stored on disk, or in the controller. In the latter case, when moving disks to another controller (server), the system has no idea what the RAID-array is supposed to look like. When the other server has a different controller (and/or firmware version), the likeliness of this being the case is higher.

To my knowledge, in the case of ProLiant SmartArray controllers, RAID-data is stored in both the controller and on disk. In the case that you are using the same controllers in both servers, you may be able to regain access by using the 'Scan Disks' functionality in the ACU (Array Configuration Utility) or SSA (Smart Storage Administrator). Make sure the SmartArray controller on your destination server is at the same firmware version or higher. You may also get a prompt during boot asking what you would like to do.

Is there any chance you can get the original system running again? That would be your best bet.

If your data is precious, get support from HP.